# Evaluating Angular expressions in Javascript strings

Tags: angularjs

This is probably an easy question, but hard to search for...

I have the text on a button changing based on some condition:

```
<button>{{buttonText()}}</button>
<script>
    $scope.buttonText = function() {
        if (condition) {
            return "Here is {{otherVar}}";
        } else {
            return "Nope!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Of course the button shows "Here is {{otherVar}}" without parsing `otherVar` into the expression.  Is there some way to have angular evaluate the js string?

The entire string gets passed from a CMS so I can't just do `return "Here is" + otherVar;`  I'm looking for something like `return angularEval("Here is {{otherVar}}");`

Comment: Why can't you just add the actual `otherVar` in the string in JS instead of using something like angularEval?

Comment: you can't evaluate expressions this way;  angular expressions only have context within the controller that they are bound to (their specific `$scope` instance).  saving an expression to a database doesn't make sense, because there isn't any way to know that that expression is going to be evaluated against the same controller, with the same variable defined.

Comment: I see.  The string is saved in a database so the client can translate it in the CMS: "Here is {{otherVar}}" for english and "Hier ist {{otherVar}}" for german.

Comment: angular has a translation module built in that you might be able to use;  if you *must* do it this way, however, you can leverage `$parse`.  something like `message = $parse("here is {{otherVar}}")($scope);` (*not tested*)

Comment: I did try using `$parse`, but got an undefined error.  Maybe because I didn't give it a `($scope)`?  Ephermeral is right though, vanillaJS is sufficient in this case.  I forgot about `replace()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button>{{buttonText()}}</button>
<script>
  //controller injects $interpolate like app.controller($scope, $interpolate)
    $scope.buttonText = function() {
        if (condition) {
            var dataObj = { otherVar : 'bla' }; //can be scope
            var exp = $interpolate('Here is {{otherVar}}');
            return exp(dataObj);
        } else {
            return "Nope!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

read more:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

also simpler solution is to put `condition` and `otherVar` in the scope and

```
<button>{{ condition ? 'Here is ' + otherVar : 'Nope!'}}</button>
```

Comment: I think my solution is better in my case, but yours perfectly answers the more general question.  I'm marking it best even though I didn't use it; hopefully it will help others.

Comment: your solution uses simple JS and could aslo be just "Here is " + otherObj, thx for the vote btw

Comment: Yeah, but in some translations otherVar was somewhere in the middle of the string.

Comment: and that is why you want some templating tool...like angular expressions instead of multiple replaces :D

Answer (score -1):

What Claies said makes sense:

> angular expressions only have context within the controller that they are bound to

VanillaJS to the rescue!

```
 return "Here is {{otherVar}}".replace('{{otherVar}}',otherVar);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$scope.otherVar = "something else";
$scope.buttonText = function (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        return "Here is " + $scope.otherVar;
    } else {
        return "Nope!";
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain how this help (maybe just a sentence or two). Just throwing some code is not considered as a good answer.